# SQL Server Calculate cumulative sum / conditional running total depending on different flags

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server with data looking like this example.

```
ID  Flag    Art.No  Amount
1   U   A1000   -100
2   U   B2000   -5
3   V   B2000   900
4   U   B2000   -10
5   I   B2000   50
6   U   B2000   -20
7   U   A1000   -50
8   I   A1000   1000
9   V   A1000   3600
10  U   A1000   -500
11  U   A1000   -100
12  U   A1000   -2000
13  I   A1000   2000
14  U   A1000   -1000
15  I   C3000   10000
16  U   C3000   -4000
17  U   B2000   -5
18  U   B2000   -5
19  I   B2000   40
20  V   B2000   200
21  U   A1000   -500
22  U   B2000   -50
23  U   C3000   -1000
```

I want to calculate ackumulated value based on the transactions. My problem is that the table contains 3 types of transactions.

1. Flag U - Sales
2. Flag I - Incoming goods
3. Flag V - Stocktaking

When Flag U and I appears the amount represent the change
When Flag V appears the amount represent the total amount when stocktaking

In words I want to find the latest V-transaction for each unice Art.No and then add or subtract U and I transactions to get a cummulativ sum for each row.
If there is no V-transaction go through the whole dataset.

I have made examples with expected result for each Art.No

A1000

```
ID  Flag    Art.No  Amount  A1000 Example
1   U   A1000   -100    
7   U   A1000   -50 
8   I   A1000   1000    
9   V   A1000   3600    3600
10  U   A1000   -500    3100
11  U   A1000   -100    3000
12  U   A1000   -2000   1000
13  I   A1000   2000    3000
14  U   A1000   -1000   2000
21  U   A1000   -500    1500
```

B2000

```
ID  Flag    Art.No  Amount  B2000 Example
2   U   B2000   -5  
3   V   B2000   900 
4   U   B2000   -10 
5   I   B2000   50  
6   U   B2000   -20 
17  U   B2000   -5  
18  U   B2000   -5  
19  I   B2000   40  
20  V   B2000   200 200
22  U   B2000   -50 150
```

C3000

```
ID  Flag    Art.No  Amount  C3000 Example
15  I   C3000   10000   10000
16  U   C3000   -4000   6000
23  U   C3000   -1000   5000
```

Edit:
To get more history in the dataset there would be nice to have values before the latest V-transaction like this

B2000

```
ID  Flag    Art.No  Amount  B2000 Example
2   U   B2000   -5  150
3   V   B2000   900 140
4   U   B2000   -10 140
5   I   B2000   50  190
6   U   B2000   -20 170
17  U   B2000   -5  165
18  U   B2000   -5  160
19  I   B2000   40  200
20  V   B2000   200 200
22  U   B2000   -50 150
```

Where each I and U transaction is taken in consideration but V-transactions is ignored.

Comment: please add some data and your query to a dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/ so we can help better (just paste the address once you run the fiddle first time)

Comment: I'm not quite following the logic required. In the A example, there's only a value after the first `V` is received. But in the B example, there's a V at ID 3 which is ignored, and only the V at Id 20 starts the count. And in the C example, there's no V's at all, but you have values. Please clarify? Also, can we assume that ID increasing is the order to be used in processing?

Comment: I think you can sum than group by article then by flag, without a fiddle to test on I cannot be sure of the query to post

Comment: The IDs will increase with each new transaction.
The Art.No can be old and have been trough several stocktakings where the one with the highest ID is the one with the most recent total count.

Comment: Here a dbfiddle link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3f864b8c539adfdef63b4a63e627a12e

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
with cte as
 (
   select *,
      -- find the latest 'V' ID per ArtNo
      max(case when Flag = 'V' then ID end) 
      over (partition by ArtNo) as Last_V_ID
   from myTable
 )
select *,
   -- cumulative sum, but ignore all rows before the latest 'V' ID
   -- includes rows when there's no 'V' ID for this ArtNo
   sum(case when ID < Last_V_ID then null else Amount end)
   over (partition by ArtNo
         order by ID
         rows unbounded preceding)
from cte
order by ArtNo, ID
```

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f6d50a959800ee9f7ca9b293d9462d6d)

Edit:

To include the data before the last stocktaking and to ignore all previous stocktakings you can use this approach:

```
with cte as
 (
   select *,
      -- find the latest 'V' ID per ArtNo
      max(case when Flag = 'V' then ID end) 
      over (partition by ArtNo) as Last_V_ID
   from [dbo].[Warehouse]
 )
select *,
   -- cumulative sum, but ignore all rows before the latest 'V' ID
   -- includes rows when there's no 'V' ID for this ArtNo
   sum(case when ID < Last_V_ID then null else Amount end)
   over (partition by ArtNo
         order by ID
         rows unbounded preceding)
   -- calculate in-stock based on last 'V' ID, discarding all previous 'V' rows
  ,sum(case when (ID < Last_V_ID and Flag <> 'V')  then -Amount 
            when ID = Last_V_ID then Amount 
       end)
   over (partition by ArtNo
         order by ID 
         rows between 1 following and unbounded following)
from cte
order by ArtNo, ID
```

Both calculations are mutually exlusive, so you can easily combine them using COALESCE.

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7fda4c4c91e100a8c31598a9b174c28b)

Comment: I have made an edit on my initial question about older transaction. I will make a try in fiddle and post a link on my progression.

Comment: Wow this is amazing. I wish i could give more than one upvote.
For a combined query see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d34b4c9b232410b43a42944744b0602e